# Sites governor limit on unauthenticated users?

Tags: force.com-sites, governorlimits

Are there any limits around how many simultaneous unauthenticated/anonymous/guest users can view a site at a given time?

I could've sworn that there was a limit that meant there could only be 10 requests from guest users at a time, but I can't find any reference to such a limit. Is there such a thing? Was there such a thing? Is it now just measured against bandwidth/service request time?

Comment: I am not aware of such a limit, it should be based on bandwith and I'm sure SF's servers will handle a lot more than that.

Answer (score 1):

For production Enterprise Edition orgs there's a bandwidth limit:

> 40,960 MB per 24 hours

and also a CPU / response generation time limit:

> 3,600 minutes per 24 hours

and a page view limit:

> 500,000 views per month

If you exceed them, you can purchase more from Salesforce. There are [good docs](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_limits.htm&language=en_US) covering exactly what counts as a page view, what counts as a calendar month, and what 'exceeding' means (110%).

Comment: Thanks. I'll hold out on marking this as best answer in case anyone confirms it's not a well documented limit, that it was a limit but no longer exists, or was never a limit.